# how to parse the formated date text in order to have the Date object in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

i have a formated date value: '20190331T141553Z', getting an invalid Date error when using the new Date('20190331T141553Z').

How to parse the formated value in order to get the Date object ？

Comment: You will have to break the characters and feed like this...

let date = new Date(2011, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 567);
alert( date ); // 1.01.2011, 02:03:04.567

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a few ways to extract the date:

## String manipulation

```js
let dateStr = '20190331T141553Z';

let year = dateStr.slice(0, 4);
let month = dateStr.slice(4, 6);
let day = dateStr.slice(6, 8);
let hours = dateStr.slice(9, 11);
let minutes = dateStr.slice(11, 13);
let seconds = dateStr.slice(13, 15);

let dateISO = `${year}-${month}-${day}T${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}Z`;
console.log(dateISO);

let date = new Date(dateISO);
console.log(date.toLocaleString());
```

As mentioned by **trincot** in a comment, the date constructor that takes each date and time part separately will treat them as *local* time, so you need to generate a string that `new Date` can parse. This would be a full [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date representation. It should be noted that technically, your string *is* ISO 8601 formatted because the delimiters (`-` and `:`) are optional. However, JavaScript officially supports [a simplified version of that standard that includes all delimiters](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15). The support for other date variations would vary between implementations, so it's best to go with the officially supported format.

## Regular Expression

Similar to using string manipulation, but shorter, as you can just use capture groups and destructuring to shorten the code.

```js
let dateStr = '20190331T141553Z';
let regex = /(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})T(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})Z/;

let [, year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds] = dateStr.match(regex);

let dateISO = `${year}-${month}-${day}T${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}Z`;
console.log(dateISO);

let date = new Date(dateISO);
console.log(date.toLocaleString());
```

## Using the Moment.js library

Almost all date related things are easier with Moment. It's a popular library for this. You don't need it for just one extraction but if you find your project will handle dates and times more, it might be worth including it.

```js
let dateStr = '20190331T141553Z';
let format = "YYYYMMDD[T]hhmmssZ";

let momentDate = moment(dateStr, format);
console.log(momentDate)

let date = momentDate.toDate();
console.log(date.toLocaleString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `replace` using a regular expression to insert the missing delimiters:

```js
var str =  '20190331T141553Z';
var dt = new Date(str.replace(/^(....)(..)(..T..)(..)(..)/, "$1-$2-$3:$4:$5"));

console.log(dt);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = '20190331T141553Z'

function timeFromString(str){
  var t = [str.substring(0,4),'-', str.substring(4,6),'-', 
  str.substring(6,8), 'T', str.substring(9,11), ':', 
  str.substring(11,13), ':', 
  str.substring(13,15)].join(',').replace(/,/g,'');
  return new Date(t);
}

timeFromString(str);
// 2019-03-31T18:15:53.000Z
```

Or you can use a regex:

```
function dateFromString(str){
    var regex = /^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})T(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/;
    return new Date(str.replace(regex, "$1-$2-$3T$4:$5:$6"));
}
```

To explain the regex:

```
// ^ means start of string
// (\d{4}) capture group 1 is 4 digits (year)
// (\d{2}) capture group 2 is 2 digits (month)
// (\d{2}) capture group 3 is 2 digits (day)
// T just matches the T
// (\d{2}) capture group 4 is 2 digits (hours)
// (\d{2}) capture group 5 is 2 digits (minutes)
// (\d{2}) capture group 6 is 2 digits (seconds)

// now we can use the numbered capture groups to replace them in the string. 
// they are auto-numbered by sequence.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function for the format provided

```
const toDate = str => {
   const year = str.slice(0, 4)
   const month = str.slice(4, 6)
   const day = str.slice(6, 8)
   const dateStrFormatted = [year, month, day].join('-')
   const timeStr = str.slice(str.indexOf('T') + 1)
   const hours = timeStr.slice(0, 2)
   const minutes = timeStr.slice(2, 4)
   const seconds = timeStr.slice(4, 6)
   const timeStrFormatted = [hours, minutes, seconds].join(':')

   return new Date(`${dateStrFormatted}T${timeStrFormatted}Z`)
}
```

Use it like so

```
const myDate = toDate('20190331T141553Z')
```

Answer (score 1):

It always seems sub–optimal to me to parse a string to create another string that is then parsed by the (notoriously fickle) built–in parser. Once you have the parts, you can give them to the Date constructor directly:

```js
function parseDate(s) {
  var b = s.match(/\d\d/g);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(b[0]+b[1],b[2]-1,b[3],b[4],b[5],b[6]));
}

console.log(parseDate('20190331T141553Z').toISOString());
```